# Is it possible to count distinct elements from all groups in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

The scenario is I perform a query such as

```
SELECT color, COUNT(DISTINCT(fruit_name))
FROM fruit
GROUP BY color
```

This as of right counts the distinct fruit_names within each group rather than the all the fruit database.

So for example if you had a fruit such as apple that can be red and green, apple will be counted twice because there will be apple in the red group and apple in the green group while I only want it counted once. I need a way to do this while keeping the group by statement.

As requested

SAMPLE DATA:

```
 fruit
 fruit_name   color

 apple         red
 apple         green
 banana        yellow
```

I want this to return a total of 2 distinct fruit names rather than 3

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: So in which group do you want that apple to be counted?

Comment: I essentially want to perform the distinct count before the groups are made, if that makes sense

Comment: That is ambiguous. Please give an example in your question. Either red or green will be left out. So what do you want? Your example is not listing counts.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. What do you want - a count of distinct fruits, REGARDLESS of color? Please show exactly what output you expect from your example.

Comment: @NikL Can you add sample OUTPUT to compliment your SAMPLE DATA

Answer (score 0):

You can select a random record for each fruit and then count the color for that:

```
select color, count(*)
from (select f.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by fruit_name order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum
      from fruit f
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by color;
```

Of course, this doesn't guarantee that every color will have a fruit, even if the original data did.

Another way is to give each fruit a weight, based on the total number of times it appears.  Then you can split the fruit among the different colors:

```
select color, count(*) as real_count, sum(weight) as weighted_count
from (select f.*, 
             1 / count(*) over (partition by fruit_name) as weight
      from fruit f
     ) t
group by color;
```

Answer (score 0):

First group by fruit_name, then by color:

```
select   color, count(*)
from     (
             select   fruit_name, min(color) as color
             from     fruit f
             group by fruit_name
         ) as names
group by color;
```